# On stripe payment failure update the subscription, what would happen to the failed invoice

Tags: django, stripe-payments, webhooks, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I am trying to downgrade the user from annual to quarterly if the payment fails.
Which will update the subscription and try to charge the user(with a new invoice) due to proration behaviour,
My question is would stripe still retry the failed invoice?

I am worried that it will charge the user 2 times.

Comment: You can always test this out in test mode with test clocks. Stripe may retry the failed invoices based on your account settings. You could also use Pending updates feature: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/pending-updates